# ios 8 action extension run on page load

Tags: ios, ios8, safari, mobile-safari, chrome-for-ios

I am trying to make an app that allows you to essentially change the default browser in iOS 8. I want it to have an action extension that runs when a page loads. When run, it should redirect the user to, for instance, "googlechrome://" and then their current page.

So far, I've created an action extension without a user interface. I know that on Mac OS X a Safari extension can be triggered by [certain events](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH17-SW5). However, it seems as if on iOS it has to manually triggered. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. All iOS extensions must be triggered by the user.